# custom bar distances in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

Using ggplot, you can change the width of a bar of a bar graph by modifying **width**:

geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge(),**width** = .9)

You can uniformly change the distance of the bars using **position_dodge()**:

geom_bar(stat="identity",**position=position_dodge(1)**,width = .9)

How do I customize the distance between bars so they are varied in a ununiform manner?

Comment: I would be helpful if you could provide an example and a sense of your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you mean. I'm assuming you mean you have a discrete x axis variable and you wish to specify custom spacing between each bar. It's possible to use `position_jitter` to get random spacing, though this also affects bar width and I'm guessing is not what you want.

I would probably handle this by using a numeric x scale and relabelling the axis with my factor levels:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:10 + rep(c(0.1, -0.1), 5), y = sample(11:20))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x, y, fill = factor(x)), color = "black", stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10 + rep(c(0.1, -0.1), 5), 
                     labels = LETTERS[1:10]) +
  guides(fill = guide_none())
```

[image]

Of course, we can only guess at what you really want since you didn't provide a motivating example.

Comment: This works but it was cumbersome to get the positioning right.  It is disappointing that barplot() allows you to do this so easily via the space function, but it is so difficult to do with ggplot().